# Difference launchPurchaseFlow and pendingIntent for in-app billing on Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm very confused by the current in-app billing documentation.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html) it says to initiate a purchase this call has to be made:

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_GAS, 10001,   
mPurchaseFinishedListener, "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#purchase) it says that a pendingIntent initiates a purchase like this

```
Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku, "inapp",
"bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");

PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
Integer.valueOf(0));
```

So which one is it? They both are API version 3 and both of these ways work independently of each other. Very confusing...

Answer (score 0):

The first uses the `IabHelper` class, which in turn uses the methods used in the second example internally. If you plan on using the `IabHelper` (which is maintained by Google and makes the API much more friendly for calling applications), then you'd use the first example. If instead you wanted to build your own In-App Billing interface, you'd use the second approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight Iain. So, the second example is part of the first example. How do I consume a purchase then, is this done via mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), purchaseToken)?

I'm asking, because when exporting my .apk and then making a purchase, consuming the purchase like this doesn't work, so the in-app purchase window only shows up once, but after that never again.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? The response from the consume call should tell you what went wrong.

Comment: I tried again today for hours and hours and it always works for the SKU "android.test.purchased", however once I use an actual sku from a product that I created and export the .apk, I always get RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR == 5 as a reponse from mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), purchaseToken). Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Assuming you've been able to do real purchases with the same app (ensuring that your signing/BILLING permission is set up correctly), the only reason I can imagine you getting a developer error would be if you aren't passing the right purchase token back. I'd consider asking another question as this is slightly tangential to the original question here.

Comment: I did actually, do you know what could be my mistake? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758242/mservice-consumepurchase3-packagename-purchasetoken-always-returns-result-de